# How should I deal with keyboard completely squeezing my dialogue box?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a dialogue box with a text label, a text fields, a dismiss button and a confirm button. Standard stuff. The problem is that when I rotate the phone and I go into portrait mode, the keyboard completely squeezes the dialogue box, which makes it unusable. My first idea was to have the dialogue box content be responsive and remove the title and buttons when the keyboard shows up, as to only have the text label and text fields on the screen. The problem I'm facing, tho, is that it appears that in Jetpack Compose just being able to check if the keyboard is currently showing is absolute hell. I've found countless ways to this, none of which were helpful or worked in my case. What should I do? My app is supposed to work in portrait mode, it would feel weird to have this single dialogue box not be responsive.